Creating new row in Gufana table
Hi I am newly using Gufana and it's fluxdb. I wrote this query to create a table showing total number of occupied and empty in a table. I used the following query
occupied = from(bucket: "custom_data")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "custom_data")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "parking_status" and r["_value"] == "occupied")
  |> count()

empt = from(bucket: "custom_data")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "custom_data")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "parking_status" and r["_value"] == "empty")
  |> count()
  
  occupied_count = occupied |> map(fn: (r) => ({ status: "occupied", count: r._value }))
  empty_count = empt |> map(fn: (r) => ({ status: "empty", count: r._value }))

 union(tables: [occupied_count, empty_count])

And the result looks like this. 
How do I add another row showing the total of the above rows?
